# Why does Amazon's Product Advertising API return "Request from blacklist...is throttled."?

Tags: throttling, amazon-product-api

I have a registered key from [Amazon's Product Advertising API (formerly ECS)](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html). I query the API to get information about the product listing for my mobile application. It was working perfectly fine. Today I have noticed that the API returns

> "Request from blacklist...is throttled".

I am well within the API call limit. What could be the reasons for this message? Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still dont know on what basis Amazon API black listed me. But i have figured out a solution around it. Make a new key pair.

Comment: This resolved a slightly different issue for me. Amazon was keeping saying to me that I was submitting too much requests even if I put a delay of 1.1 second or more.
I generated a new key pair and didn't get more error Messages.
Thanks !